# Updating Rows Based on Multiple Tables in SQL Server Compact Edition

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

How to Updating Rows Based on Multiple Tables in SQL Server Compact Edition ?

I have two tables in a database. ActivatedProducts and DocumentSettings.I added new column (UID) in DocumentSettings table,i want to put that UID data from ActivatedProducts (ID) Table with respect to ProductID from ActivatedProducts table

following query's also not working please help me

```
UPDATE DocumentSettings
SET UID = 
    (
        SELECT ActivatedProducts.ID
        FROM ActivatedProducts
        WHERE DocumentSettings.TitleID = ActivatedProducts.ProductID
    )


UPDATE A
    SET A.UID = B.ID
FROM DocumentSettings A, ActivatedProducts B
WHERE A.TitleID = B.ProductID


UPDATE DocumentSettings 
    SET [UID]=AP.[ID] 
FROM  DocumentSettings DS  
INNER JOIN ActivatedProducts AP ON DS.[Titleid]=AP.[ProductID]
```

Comment: And reading those queries - **WHAT** exactly is it you're trying to do?!?!? It's not getting very clear from your three separate queries there......

Answer (score 3):

The last time I checked, SQL Server CE **still** does not support UPDATE-FROM-JOIN syntax.  All 3 you have shown will work in Sql Server proper, but in CE, you will need to programmatic-ally retrieve each value for updating in a loop.

Reference[: UPDATE (SQL Server Compact - 2008)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174122.aspx)

Answer (score -2):

You can do it as per below

```
    UPDATE [table one]
        SET [table one].result = [table two] .results
        FROM [table one] T1
        INNER JOIN [table three] t3
         on t1.reg_id = t3.reg_id
        INNER JOIN [table two] T2
         on t2.venue = t3.venue
```